# Какие бесплатные компиляторы под Windows 10 или Ubuntu 18.04 поддерживают режим K&R C?

Tags: c

Мне нужен компилятор, для которого я смогу установить режим стандарта K&R C при отсутствии одновременной возможности использовать расширения языка других стандартов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На счет собственно K&R C (то есть версии, которая описывается в первой редакции *книги* K&R C) не знаю, но мне кажется, C89 (по которому написана вторая редакция) - это достаточно близко.

GCC и Clang в C89 умеют. Для него используются флаги `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors`.

MinGW-w64 (порт GCC для Windows, на текущий момент GCC 8.1) можно скачать тут: [тык](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download).

А вот MSVC (Visual Studio), насколько я понимаю, не умеет. В мануале [нашелся](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017) флаг для выбора стандарта С++, но не С.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, по K&R "int main (int argc, char **argv) {return 0;}" собираться не должно. А собирается.

Comment: с89 и с90 — это уже ANSI C, а K&R — это нечто совсем ламповое, существовавшее до официальной стандартизации... не совсем понятно с какой целью OP'у нужен именно он...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Можете показать, где там это написано? Там везде примеры с `main() {...}`, и они собираются. Но там вроде нет запрета на `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, во втором издании (1988 г.) действительно есть main (int argc, char *argv[]). Очевидно, я ошибся.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev А я-то подумал, вы про отсутствие возвращаемого  типа... Если не секрет, зачем вам такая старая версия языка?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Перечитал википедию еще раз, согласен. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё, нашёл, откуда у меня эта ложная память. В "Unix Programming Environment" (Kernighan, Pike, 1984) main выглядела так: "main (argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[]; {...}". А мне она низачем, я не OP :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Ой, пардон. :)

Comment: Мне для начала изучения языка нужна эта версия.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Я бы сразу учился на самой последней версии. Иначе потом переучиваться. Вообще, из новых версий С почти никогда не убирают фичи. Вам только придется заменить `main() {...}` на `int main() {... return 0;}`, а почти все остальное - то же самое.

Comment: Последняя версия, 2011 года, не полностью поддерживается. Например, языковые потоки не работают.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Ой, поверьте, не нужно... Для того, чтоб ездить на автомобиле, не начинают учиться запрягать лошадь. Сначала приучиться к `int f(a,b) int a; char * b; { ...}`, чтоб потом опять учиться `int f(int a, char* b)`? Или приучаться писать `int f(void)`? Стоит ли оно того - учиться "назад", а не "вперед"?

Comment: Меня пугает обилие ключевых слов в новых стандартах и то, что все их придётся анализировать и вникать в детали. Разве оба варианта не поддерживаются в современных сборщиках? Для меня сейчас ключевой аспект - производительность.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов Не хотите учить новый стандарт - учите хотя бы C90, который поддерживается всеми современными компиляторами. Зачем учить мертвый диалект языка?

Comment: А что я буду делать, когда в открытой библиотеке я встречу мёртвый диалект, а сдавать проект завтра?

Comment: Говорю же, все, что было *убрано* в новых стандартах можно пересчитать по пальцам. Скорее всего не встретите, а в крайнем случае можно нагуглить.

Comment: Прочесть и разобраться в старом коде, зная новый, вы сможете. Это как с иностранными языками - зная С99, прочесть (может, не написать) K&R C вы точно сможете. А ведь программист, как чукча из анекдота - в основном писатель...